# Delete eth0 avahi from the ifconfig list

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ifconfig, wired

Hello this is the response I get from ifconfig. Now I have two eth0 things being showed up. I need to delete the second one which says eth0:avahi. I posted my ifconfig's response on a site as I has problem using wired internet, and they suggested to remove the eth0 avahi, to get internet.

But I am a newbie to linux networking and have no idea how to delete this.

response for ifconfig

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:a9:05:22:cd:f9
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Interrupt:28 Base address:0x4000

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:a9:05:22:cd:f9
inet addr:169.254.10.43 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
Interrupt:28 Base address:0x4000

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:64016 (64.0 KB) TX bytes:64016 (64.0 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:26:82:3c:ac:27
inet6 addr: fe80::226:82ff:fe3c:ac27/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:52142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:30404 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:60816983 (60.8 MB) TX bytes:4160159 (4.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in your interfaces file? (Not sure if this is the correct place in Ubuntu 10.04)

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

If avahi is list there, try deleting it.

Comment: auto lo iface lo inet loopback this is the content in /etc/network/interfaces file

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you see the eth0:avahi device is that eth0 has no working IP networking (it has no IP-address).  Once eth0 works, eth0:avahi should go away automatically, so you shouldn't care about it.

Now, about the best way to fix this, it would be useful to know whether this is a desktop or a server...

Comment: I am using a desktop

Comment: Most likely your network doesn't have a DHCP server, or it is not working corrently, so if you want to be able to use the internet either you need to configure a fixed IP address in the subnet that your network uses, or you need to fix the DHCP server.  You can set a fixed IP address in the Network Connections control panel (under System -> Preferences).  In case you know you have a DHCP server (e.g. in your home router), you should check why it doesn't work (maybe it restricts which MAC addresses can get an address?).